# Why is the image button id not recognize

Tags: asp.net

Why can't i call ImageButton.ImageUrl??

Default.aspx:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="Test1.jpg" CommandName="Delete" OnCommand="ImageButton_Command" />



 </asp:Content>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
void ImageButton_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)  
      {  
       string name = ***ImageButton1.ImageUrl***; //(Error)
```

}

Comment: and what does the error say?

Comment: CS0122: Default2.ImageButton_Command (Object, System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs) because the security is not accessible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason from the code provided for this control not to be recognised; it could be a discrepancy between your `.aspx` and `.aspx.cs` files (does the former properly relate to the latter?), or it could just be a build problem, have you done a complete clean and rebuild?

A solution, regardless of why this is happening for your current situation could be this:

```
protected void ImageButton_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e) {
  var button = sender as ImageButton;
  if (button != null) {
    string name = button.ImageUrl;
  }
}
```

It's important to do the null check here, since technically this event handler could be called by something other than the button(s) subscribed to raise the event, even though this *shouldn't* be the case.

Comment: CS0122: Default2.ImageButton_Command (Object, System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs) because the security is not accessible

Comment: Try making the event handler method `public` or `protected`.